# Setting a value to a parameter in the Constructor (C#)

Tags: c#

Hello i was just wondering if this is valid

```
    public test( string name, double kpiScore, bool isPrivate = false)
    {

   

    this.name = name;

     
        this.kpiScore = score;


        this.isPrivate = isPrivate;

        

}
```

Can i set the bool isPrivate = false, in the parameter call? Or do i set it in the block itself. I've never seen it where the parameter is set within the parameter call. I've looked online and no one mentions this.  -- this is the original uml diagram, i modified it  just to make the problem simpler.

[image]

Comment: My 2 cents: if you are blindly following the UML diagram you probably aren't writing particularly good code. Make sure you understand the intent behind the UML before you write the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a big difference between

```
public test( string name, double score, bool isPrivate = false)
{
   this.name = name;
   this.kpiScore = score;
   this.isPrivate = isPrivate;
}
```

and

```
public test( string name, double score)
{
   this.name = name;
   this.kpiScore = score;
   this.isPrivate = false;
}
```

in the first case the caller can do

```
var t = new test("x", 42);
```

or

```
var t = new test("x", 42, true);
```

ie they can choose to override the privacy option. In the second case they do not have that choice. So the answer depends on what your end goal is

Comment: thanks for the help, i'm going to edit my question so it's a bit more clear

Comment: i think i would probably like to override the option, there is no specification on what i'm supposed to do, no documentation i've seen online that mentions this specific case.

Comment: @Ilda  the UML says you should use the first one,, now that you have editined the questin

Comment: Thank you so much man, appreciate it after getting angry comments earlier.